# Connect to mssql in docker container

Tags: python, sql-server, docker, docker-compose

Can't connect to mssql in docker container Code piece for connecting mssql in python:

```
def connectsql():
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
        "mssql+pymssql://service name")
    ms_sql_conn = engine.connect()
    df = pd.read_sql('select * from table name',
                     ms_sql_conn,
                     parse_dates=["rest_date"])
    ms_sql_conn.close()

    return df
```

When I run the script, the connection is successful, but when I try to put this code in docker, there is no connection. As I understand it, I need to write something in the environment in the docker-compose file, but I don’t understand what exactly and do I need python code for this? Dockerfile contents:

```
FROM python:3
RUN pip install --upgrade pip --default-timeout=100 future
WORKDIR /check
COPY . /check
RUN pip install  -r requirements.txt

CMD [ "python", "/check/bot2.py" ]
```

docker-compose content:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  bot2:
    image: first
    build: ./
    restart: always
```

I tried to register a connection in the environment, but it didn’t work out and I also don’t know if I need to change the python code then?

i tried to connect via pymssql:

```
def connectsql2():
    conn = pymssql.connect(
        host=r'*******\********',
        user=r'*******',
        password=r'******',
        database='****',
    )
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select * from *********")
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print(row)
    return row
```

But I am getting this error: pymssql._pymssql.OperationalError: (20009, b'DB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (******)\n')

Answer (score 0):

In your docker compose file you need add two line:

```
extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"

version: '3.1'

services:
  bot2:
    image: first
    build: ./
    restart: always
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

Comment: I tried to add, nothing changed, it gives an error:
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymssql._pymssql.OperationalError) (20009, b'DB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist